# Is it possible to prove the derivative of sine geometrically without arc length?

Tags: calculus, geometry, limits, euclidean-geometry, angle

There are a great many ways to prove that the derivative of sine is cosine, some of them based on things like the Taylor series definition.  I’d like to prove it using only the right-triangle definition of trigonometric functions.  But all the proofs I’ve seen involve the notion of the arclength of a circular arc subtended by a given angle and/or the notion of the area of a sector subtended by a given angle.

My question is, is it possible to prove that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$ and hence $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x) =\cos(x)$ without invoking the notions of the arclength of a circular arc or the area of a sector?  After all, it is perfectly possible to define the measure of an angle without referring to arclength; it’s done in most modern axiomatizations of Euclidean geometry, like [this one](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~scott/mat515.fall14/smsg.pdf):

> Postulate $11$. 
>   Angle Measurement Postulate. To every angle there corresponds a real number between $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$. 
>   Postulate $12$. 
>   Angle Construction Postulate. Let $AB$ be a ray on the edge of the half-plane $H$. For every $r$ between $0$ and $180$ there is exactly one ray $AP$, with $P$ in $H$ such that $m \angle PAB = r$. 
>   Postulate $13$. 
>   Angle Addition Postulate. If $D$ is a point in the interior of $\angle BAC$, then $m \angle BAC = m \angle BAD + m \angle DAC$. 
>   Postulate $14$. 
>   Supplement Postulate. If two angles form a linear pair, then they are supplementary.

So using axioms like these, is it possible to prove that $\sin(x)\leq x \leq \tan(x)$, which is what’s needed to prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$ and hence $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x) =\cos(x)$?

Comment: The inequalities are valid only if the angle is measured in radians. So you'd better rewrite your postulate using $\pi$ instead of $180°$.

Comment: And of course, the measure of an angle in radians is related to the length of an arc. I don't think it's possible to avoid that.

Comment: The problem is not so much about degrees and radians. The issue is in the definition of the circular function. Given a number $x$ how exactly do we find (at least in theory) $\sin x$ or $\sin x^{\circ} $? If you can answer this question precisely then you can also find the desired derivative rigorously.

Comment: @Aretino That’s a trivial matter, you can just define the number of radians as $\frac{\pi}{180}$ times the number of degrees.

Comment: Of course, but the presence of $\pi$ implies that a circle is somehow involved.

Comment: For example, let's say that corresponding to each positive real $x$ there exists another unique real number called logarithm of $x$ denoted by $\log x$. This statement does not really define the logarithmic function, but rather it specifies an arbitrary function from $\mathbb{R} ^{+} $ to $\mathbb {R} $. Thus postulate $11$ does not exactly tell you about how one measures an angle precisely.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I think Postulates $11-14$ together give you enough information to tell you what the measure of any given angle is.  In any case, if you want an algorithm for computing the sine of a given number $x$, here is one (there’s probably a better one).  The axioms of geometry are enough to derive the half-angle and sum formulas for sine and cosine.  Using those, you can compute the sine of any dyadic fraction multiple of $\pi$.  And then for any real number $x$ just take a sequence $q_n$ of dyadic fraction multiples of $\pi$ converging to $x$ and take the limit of $sin(q_n)$.

Comment: Then write a formula based on this algorithm for $\sin x^{\circ} $ (it must be algebraic in nature) and then differentiate it.

Comment: And in fact you should be able to eastablish as a first step the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n\sin (180^{\circ}/2^n)=L$ exists and is positive. Further using this limit you can prove that area of a circle is $Lr^2$ if $r$ is its radius. I think the job is done using dyadic rationals and limits to get $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin (180x)^{\circ}}{x}=L$.

Comment: And then $$(\sin x^{\circ}) '=\frac{L} {180}\cos x^{\circ} $$ comes out naturally.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I found [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2688970) which does what you’re suggesting.  But then I found an even simpler way to prove the derivative of sine, in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2689051).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The last paragraph of the second paper says “Looking at this result from a more usual geometric approach, suppose that we had started with the assumption that a measure exists for directed angles, which is additive for adjacent angles and preserved under congruence. We could define S and C within the usual cartesian framework, taking the right angle as having unit measure. From this all the rest follows, with no need of arc length, area, integration, or infinite sums.” So it looks like postulates $11-14$ do suffice to prove the derivative of sine.

Comment: That paper in your comment is really small in length and high in content. +1 for your question and comment.